# How to layer elements with CSS position property?

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, position

I've looked at all the questions on here asking the same thing and tried every suggestion, none of it is working for me.

I want to layer two dynamically created canvas elements on top of each other, inside the div with an id of "plotPlaceholder".

It continues to just show one below the other, like so:

[image]

```js
// grab elements from form
var wid = document.getElementById("wid").value;
var hei = document.getElementById("hei").value;

// grab div container and create canvas elements
var canvasPlaceholder = document.getElementById("plotPlaceholder");
var baseCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var canvasElement = document.createElement("canvas");

canvasElement.width = wid;
canvasElement.height = hei;
baseCanvas.width = wid;
baseCanvas.height = hei;
baseCanvas.style.zIndex = "1";
canvasElement.style.zIndex = "2";
    
baseCanvas.id = "canvasToHoldGrid";
canvasElement.id = "plottingCanvas";
canvasPlaceholder.appendChild(baseCanvas);
canvasPlaceholder.appendChild(canvasElement);
```

```css
canvas {
    border: 2px solid #27a3ea;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#plotPlaceholder {
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="plotPlaceholder"></div>
```

Comment: what element has `id` of wid and hei?

Comment: Right now it gets an error because it can't get a value from `null`

Comment: Something like this? See [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9qafb0th/)

Comment: @leo.fcx yes exactly like that. It must be something else messing it up in that case.

Comment: Well, you got something to start with ... good luck! :)

Comment: thank you very much! @leo.fcx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was happening - there was an extra div being created (parent of the canvas elements) with a class of 'canvas-container'. The position property was being overwritten.

```
.canvas-container {
    position: absolute !important;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

That `!important` fixed it, although I'm sure it's not best practice in most circumstances.